Prove that the perpendiculars from the A-excenter, B-excenter, C-excenter to BC,AC,AB are concurrent.
Recently, I encountered this Romania TST 2010 Problem:

Let ABC be a scalene triangle, let I be it's incenter, and let $A_1,B_1,C_1$ be the points of contact of the excircles with the sides $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. Prove that the circumcircles of the triangles $AIA_1,BIB_1,$ and $CIC_1$ have a common point different from I.

I started drawing the diagram, until I encountered an interesting property: The perpendiculars from $E_a,E_b,E_c$ (where $E_x$ is the x-excenter) to lines $BC,AC,AB$ appear to be concurrent at a point!
Can someone provide a proof, and if this point has been studied before, the name of the point, and some useful properties?
EDIT: Here is a diagram with the point and the perpendiculars mentioned. 

The point of concurrence you are examining, I'll call it $M$, is the circumcenter of the excentral triangle. I do not know of a name for it.
A proof: Consider the angles at $A,B,C$ as $2\alpha, 2\beta, 2\delta$. With some angle chasing you will find that, e.g., on line $E_bE_c$ altitudes from $AC$ and $AB$ will cut off equal angles $\alpha$, hence they meet at $M$ to form an isosceles triangle, whose own altitude to $M$ will have a foot on the midpoint of $E_bE_c$. But this argument applies to any side, and this is exactly the way to find the circumcenter of a triangle, so $M$ is the circumcenter of $E_aE_bE_c$.

Bevan point is how it's called.

Nice! I thought there was also a proof using Menelaus' Theorem, but I'll do some more research into this point and its uses later on.
